# How do you describe trying to balance two opposite priorities?

Tags: phrase-request

How do you describe trying to balance two opposite priorities? I was hoping I could say "walk a thin line" or something, but I'm not sure anymore (I haven't found such an idiom). I need a verbal phrase that describes the **action**, **not the state** of facing a difficult choice

> He felt obliged to tell the truth but was unwilling to upset her. He was <s>between a rock and a hard place</s> *trying to walk a thin line*

Comment: How about [on the horns of a dilemma](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-horns-of-a-dilemma)?

Comment: @KateBunting please reread the bold part

Comment: Perhaps he was *trying to balance* the two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually "walk a fine line" is a common idiom, very close to your "walk a thin line".

"Walk a tightrope" is another applicable idiom.

Or you could be literal. "He was struggling to balance telling the truth with not upsetting her." Or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can describe this as a [**balancing act**](https://www.theidioms.com/balancing-act/), i.e. as a person walking a tightrope or a balance beam, as they can't "lean" too far to either side without falling. I think this is what you were trying to get to with "walking a thin line". For somebody who has to manage more than two opposed ideas, or several competing interests, you can refer to that as [**juggling**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/juggle) their priorities, or "trying to keep all the balls in the air" as a more descriptive way to put it.

Comment: With respect, I asked for a verbal phrase, not a noun phrase. "Keep all the balls in the air" is too metaphorical. One wouldn't probably guess the implied meaning

Comment: "Balancing act" and "juggling priorities" are good. But "trying to keep all the balls in the air" is normally used to mean that a person is very busy, not that he has to decide between competing goals. Competing priorities in the sense of "I have so many things to do I don't know which to do first", rather than competing priorities in the sense of "there are good reasons to do X but also good reasons to do not X".

Answer (score -1):

Stuck between a rock and a hard place?

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].

Comment: With respect, I explicitly ruled it out in my question